# Get custom product page ID within the app?

Tags: ios, swift, app-store

So recently Apple released [Custom Product Pages](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/custom-product-pages/), which works by adding the `ppid` parameter to the link (e.g. `https://apps.apple.com/app/id0000000000?ppid=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx`)

But I didn't find any information on how to understand **from which** `ppid` used installed the app!

Does anybody have some experience with it? Can it be parsed from `launchOptions` or something?

Comment: Have you managed to resolve the question?

Comment: @rkyr nope, I guess there's no way to get ppid from the app

Comment: @BohdanPodvirnyi that really sucks... We've been hoping to leverage custom product pages in our strategy but it doesn't make sense if the app can't recognise what custom page was used to install it  :(

Comment: @matthewfx same, I think I'll try to file a feature request, maybe someone will notice